# Properties of finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-rings

Suppose $R$ is a finite ring. It may be commutative or it may be not. Let $x \in R$.

1. Show that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $x^n = x^{2n}$.
2. Is it true that $x^{k!} = x^{2k!}$, where $k = |R|$?

---

In the first part should we take random $x$ and consider its powers, then use pigeonhole principle, to show that some powers must coincide? Or is there better way to tackle first problem?

For the second problem do we have to provide a counter-example in form of the ring modulo prime and show that if first statement is true second will not hold?

Comment: Note that if the first statement is true, and it you can show that $n\le k$, then the second statement is true as well.

Comment: @Jsevillamol In the second part if we take $R$ modulo prime $p$, then for $x = 0$ the equality holds always. If $x \ne 0$ and we have a multiplicative group then ${x^{p - 1}} = 1$ will hold. Then we can take any $k \geq p - 1$ and we get ${x^{k!}} = 1$ from where it follows that ${x^{k!}} = {x^{2k!}}$ and $k$ must not necessarily be equal to $\left| R \right|$ which is $p$ is our example.

Comment: I do not see what you are arriving at. I was noting that if $\exists n\le k=|R|$ such that $x^n=x^{2n}$ then $x^{k!}=x^{2*3*\dots*n*\dots*k}=x^{2*3*\dots*2n*\dots*k}=x^{2\cdot k!}$

Comment: @Jsevillamol we assume that both parts are independent from each other. So i think we need to solve the first part first. In your notation you are using the information from second part. I was thinking is it possible to proof fisrt part by induction if we consider first proble as idempotent element of a ring?

Comment: @user1812 In 2. I think you want it for every $x\in R$.

Comment: @user26857 that is all information that was given. Perhaps you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let $x\in R$. Since $R$ is finite, there are some positive integers $k$ and $l$ such that $x^k=x^{k+l}$.
   Then 
   $$(x^{kl})^2=x^{kl}x^{kl}=x^{k(l-1)}(x^k x^l)x^{l(k-1)}=x^{k(l-1)}x^{k+l}x^{l(k-1)}=x^{k(l-1)}x^{k}x^{l(k-1)}=x^{kl}x^{l(k-1)}=\cdots =x^{kl},$$ so $x^{kl}$ is an idempotent.
2. Set $n=|R|$. For $x\ne 0$ we can choose $k,k+l\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ since the set $\{0,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$ has $n+1$ elements. (If $x^m=0$ for some $1<m\le n$, then $x^m=x^{2m}$.) Then $kl\mid n!$. This shows that $x^{n!}=x^{2n!}$ (for all $x\in R$).

Comment: So you use the distributive property of the ring to show that ${x^{kl}}$ is an idempotent?

Comment: @user1812 Right.

Comment: Looks good! Thank you user26857 !

Comment: Nice work on 1, but not sure how you're proving 2. First, what if $x^{n-1} \neq 0$ but $x^n = 0$ ? Second, how do you get $x^{n!} = x^{2n!}$?

Comment: First, I can't see any issue if $x^n=0$. Second, I suggest to take a look at the other answer for all needed details. (It was a typo in my answer which I fixed. Thanks for drawing my attention to this.)

Answer (score 1):

Building on @user26857's answer: it is possible to find $k, \ell$ such that $k + \ell \leq |R|$. Intuitively, $\ell$ is the length of the cycle containing $x^k$, which cannot exceed $|R|$, and $k$ is the distance from $x$ to an element that is part of a multiplicative cycle; by the pigeonhole principle we can assume minimal values such that $k \leq |R| - \ell$.

If $k \neq \ell$, then $k \ell$ divides $|R|!$, hence for any natural number $z$, $x^{z|R|!}=x^{zm(k\ell)}=x^{k\ell}$.
If $k = \ell$, then $k, \ell \leq |R| / 2$, and $k$ and $2\ell$ are both terms in the product $|R|!=(|R|)(|R|-1)\cdots(1)$; again, $k\ell$ divides $|R|!$, and we have $x^{z|R|!}=x^{zm^\prime(k\ell)}=x^{k\ell}$.
In either case, $x^{|R|!}=x^{2|R|!}$.

Comment: I've already did that part, too.

Comment: My bad; I hadn't seen your edit.